# F# Generating all possible combinations between two lists

Tags: f#

I want to generate all possible combinations between two lists. For example, if I had list1: [1,2] and list2: [a,b]. It would produce a list that contains [(1,a),(1,b),(2,a),(2,b)].
I am trying to figure out how to do this with recursion and match expressions.
I am currently stuck with this:

```
let rec combo (a1: 'a list) (a2: 'b list) =
    match a1,a2 with
    | [],[] -> []
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? It seems very similar to your other recent question in the way it's phrased.

Comment: No I've found problems online and trying to write solutions to learn F#.

Comment: OK. What did you think of the answers to your previous question? If those answers were helpful, I think you might be able to apply a similar approach here as well.

Comment: Yes I attempted to use the solutions from my other questions to answer this one. However, I am still unsure how to complete this solution.

Comment: Can you post your attempts to apply the other answers' solutions and describe what went wrong with them?

Answer (score 0):

Divide your task. First, write a function that returns a list of pairs formed from a single value and the items in a list (it'll be your second list).

```
let rec makePairs x lst acc = 
    match lst with
    | [] -> acc
    | _  -> makePairs x (List.tail lst) (acc @ [(x, List.head lst)])

// makePairs 'a' [5;7] [] yields [('a',5), ('a',7)]
```

Then, by the same pattern as in `makePairs`, write a function `makeAllPairs lst1 lst2 acc` that enumerates the items of the first list and collects the pairs for the item returned from `makePairs`.

A simpler version of makePairs:

```
let makePairs2 x lst = List.map (fun b -> (x, b)) lst
```